# Queryset and template - How can I optimise my code?

Tags: django

How can I optimise my code?

This is my views and template example:

**views:**

```
def index(request):
    recomended = MyPost.objects.filter(recomented=True).order_by('add_date')
    posts = MyPost.objects.all()[:9]
    return render_to_response('main.html',{'recomended': recomended, 'posts':posts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**main.html**

```
<h1>Website</h1>
{% for r in recomended %}
    {{ r.title }}
    {{ r.url }}
{% endfor %}

{% for p in posts %}
    {{ p.title }}
    {{ p.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why do you think it needs to be optimised?

Comment: You are not passing `recomended`, `posts` to template though, is that your actual code?

Comment: post and recomended could be extracted from 1 queryset as far as I can see

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide What do you mean?

Comment: `qs = MyPost.objects.all(); recommended = qs.filter(recomented=True).order_by('add_date'); posts = qs[:9]` or just send `qs` to the template and filter there

Answer (score 0):

To give a generic answer to the question in the title I'd say:

1. Be really sure you need to optimize before doing so. Is something slow or are you just being a perfectionist? If it's the latter, use your time to build new features instead.
2. Install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) for all your projects. The SQL tab in there will tell you if you're running an unusually large number of queries for something. The detail on that tab will tell you where the queries are being generated.
3. Fix any obvious errors first.
4. If there aren't obvious errors in your views or templates then try using `select_related` or `prefetch_related` if you're using any foreignkey or manytomany relationships.
5. If all else fails, try raw SQL.